# COUNTIFS with AND & OR, Including < and > Operators

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, countif

Column A contains dates. Column B contains dates and text values.

I'd like to write a formula that counts everything where (A:A <= DATE) AND (B:B > DATE OR B:B = "TextValue")

I know you can incorporate OR into countif using a formula like `SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{value1, value2}))`, but I have too many date values and want to use the > operator in the OR part.

I know this is a weird one with dates and text in the same column. Any help is appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to count the number of rows that satisfy all the logical condition: A AND (C OR D), where each letter represents a logical condition. You can use in `G2` the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( --(B2:B5<=E2), 
--((--(C2:C5 > E2) + (--(C2:C5 = DATEVALUE(E4)))) > 0) )
```

or using `LET` function to represent better each conditions:

```
=LET(cond1, --(B2:B5 <= E2), cond2, --(C2:C5 > E2), 
 cond3, --(C2:C5 = DATEVALUE(E4)),
 SUMPRODUCT(cond1, --((cond2 + cond3) > 0))
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

The first row satisfies `cond1`, and the last row satisfies `cond3`.

Since you indicated the last condition is against a text value (`E4`) we need to convert it to a date using `DATEVALUE`.

`SUMPRODUCT` is expecting numeric values, so each logical condition needs to be converted to `1`,`0` values via `--()` operator. The OR condition is establish as a sum of two binary values and it should be greater than `0`.

You can not use `COUNTIFS` in a scenario like this, because each criteria represents a simple comparison condition such as: `"<="&E2` (for `cond1` for example) internally it checks the condition: `B2:B5 <= E2`, i.e. a single logical condition where the left hand side appears only once. For an OR condition you need two logical conditions (i.e. `OR(rng < a, rng > b)`). In order to count a row all the conditions must be satisfied (logical AND), so there is no way to consider an OR condition with this function.